# Why am i getting Attempt to de-reference a null object error?

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
public class oneTestHomepageclass{

    public string usernameinput{get; set;}
    public string passwordinput{get; set;}
    public list<user_account__c> userpasslist{get; set;}
    public boolean userfound{get; set;}
    public string warningmessage{get; set;}
    public oneTesthomepageclass(){

        userpasslist = [Select username__c,password__c from user_account__c];

}    
    public pagereference login(){

        pagereference pg = new pagereference('/apex/testcheckpage');
        for(user_Account__c userpass : userpasslist)
            {    

            if(userpass.username__c==usernameinput && userpass.password__c==passwordinput )
                  userfound=true;
                  else
                  userfound=false;

            }
        if(userfound)
        return pg;
        else
            {
                warningmessage = 'User not found/Password incorrect, Please try again';
                return null;
            }


    }
}
```

i am getting the error for the line if(userfound) , so when I use if(userfound==true) then it works fine, but i was told to use if(userfound) as it improves readability.
why am i getting that error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please initialize your variable userfound with default value as in line if(userfound) it is referring to if(null)

Sample Initiallizing

userfound = False;

```
public class oneTestHomepageclass{

    public string usernameinput{get; set;}
    public string passwordinput{get; set;}
    public list<user_account__c> userpasslist{get; set;}
    public boolean userfound{get; set;}
    public string warningmessage{get; set;}
    public oneTesthomepageclass(){

        userpasslist = [Select username__c,password__c from user_account__c];

}    
    public pagereference login(){
        userfound = False;
        pagereference pg = new pagereference('/apex/testcheckpage');
        for(user_Account__c userpass : userpasslist)
            {    

            if(userpass.username__c==usernameinput && userpass.password__c==passwordinput )
                  userfound=true;
                  else
                  userfound=false;

            }
        if(userfound)
        return pg;
        else
            {
                warningmessage = 'User not found/Password incorrect, Please try again';
                return null;
            }


    }
}
```

Comment: but am i not using the if condition correctly above it, it should be initialized with true or false before reaching line if(userfound). Also isn't if(userfound) and if(userfound==true) the same thing, Isn't if(userfound)  checking if userfound is true(userfound==true).

Comment: if(userfound==true)  Means you are checking userfound is true or not and in this case it will not satisfy the condition as it will be if(null == true).

Can you please check if it is going in the for loop. In your situation I think it is not going in for loop for(user_Account__c userpass : userpasslist)

Comment: it is going in for loop because it works fine when i use if(userfound)."it will be if(null == true)", my concern exactly, why though as i am initializing above it.

Comment: Can you please reference the document by salesforce https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_variables.htm